# Ace editor change field focus on tab key

Tags: javascript, html, css, ace-editor

I have some textfields and field with Ace editor. 
When I change focus by tab key editor types tab inside his area but I want to set focus on the next field.

For example:

```
<input type="text"/>
<div class="panel-body">
     <div id="editor"></div>
</div>
<input type="text"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rY37e/34/

Comment: So, you want directly focus on next input text. Not in editor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
editor.commands.bindKey("Tab", null)
editor.commands.bindKey("Shift-Tab", null)
```

to allow the brwoser to handle tab key